# Reading a text file with new lines in Java

Tags: java, file

I want to read my text file with new lines, for example, I have that txt file ;

> I'm a paragraph. Click here to add your own text and edit me. It?s
> easy. Just click ?Edit Text? or double click me to add your own
> content and make changes to the font. Feel free to drag and drop me
> anywhere you like on your page. I?m a great place for you to tell a
> story and let your users know a little more about you.
>
> This is a great space to write long text about your company and your
> services. You can use this space to go into a little more detail about
> your company. Talk about your team and what services you provide. Tell
> your visitors the story of how you came up with the idea for your
> business and what makes you different from your competitors. Make your
> company stand out and show your visitors who you are.

and I want to read that file as seems.

I tried this code:

```
FileReader fr = 
  new FileReader("C:\\Users\\pankaj\\Desktop\\test.txt"); 

int i; 
while ((i=fr.read()) != -1) 
  System.out.print((char) i); 
}
```

But it gets without newlines.

Is there any way to get text file with newlines?

Comment: `Files.lines(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\pankaj\\Desktop\\test.txt"))`

Comment: these are not working for my issue, I want to keep in string variable with new lines. Thanks for contribution

Comment: Your code works fine for me. What java version are you using? I am using JDK 15.0.1

Comment: The code as shown will also read newlines. It is unclear what your real problem is.

Comment: I just want to keep the txt file in a string variable with new lines

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathToYourFile))) {
    String line = br.readLine();

    while (line != null) {
        // do something with your line, like printing it or appending to a StringBuilder
        System.out.println(line);
        line = br.readLine();
    }
}
```

Or check out the other possibilities from the answeres [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/reading-a-plain-text-file-in-java) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-do-i-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Scanner class

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);       
while (sc.hasNextLine())  {
      System.out.println(sc.nextLine()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any Reader that supports readLine(), which reads the next line of the text without the ending line separator - but you can just add that using System.lineSeparator().

Another approach is to read all bytes in the file and convert that into a string. There are multiple utility methods in the java.nio.file.Files class.
Example:

```
RandomAccessFile raf=new RandomAccessFile(yourFile,"r");
String text="";
for(String line=raf.readLine();line!=null;line=raf.readLine()){
text+=line+System.lineSeparator();
}
```

Example 2:

```
String text=Files.readString(yourPath);
```

Example 3:

```
String text=new String(Files.readAllLines(yourPath), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```